# Extracting from a tar file - Default behavior: overwrite or keep?

Tags: bash

In the [documentation](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/en/man1/tar.1.html), I read that `tar` has the following options when extracting files from a tarball:

```
-k, --keep-old-files
           don't replace existing files when extracting
--overwrite
           overwrite existing files when extracting
```

which one is used by default?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can try it by yourself:

```
echo 1 > 1
echo 2 > 2
tar cf foo.tar 1 2
echo 3 > 1
echo 4 > 2
tar xf foo.tar
cat ?
1
2
```

First two files (`1` and `2`) were created. Than an archive `foo.tar` was created. The next step changed the file contents and after that `foo.tar` was extracted. If you look into the files you'll see the old contents.

So `--overwrite` is default.

Comment: the default is: --overwrite-dir
           overwrite metadata of existing directories when extracting
           (default)

Comment: And an explanation of the behavior:  http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Dealing-with-Old-Files.html